# How to interactively (visually) resolve conflicts in SourceTree / git

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using (Windows) SourceTree for my git project. I can do it in either command prompt or Linux terminal.

But, I'm wondering whether there is a nice way to interactively and visually resolve conflicts. For example, if pull detects conflicts, popping up a GUI-based conflict tool (e.g., P4Merge). Is it possible?

I am always doing manual conflict resolving, which is just painful.

This is, for example, a git `pull` message, from SourceTree.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false pull --no-commit origin master
From W:\repo\
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD   

Updating 33c07bf..41e0249

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    foo.cpp
    goo.cpp
    goo.hpp
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting    

Completed with errors, see above.
```

Answer (score 159, accepted):

From SourceTree, click on Tools->Options.  Then on the "General" tab, make sure to check the box to allow SourceTree to modify your Git config files.

Then switch to the "Diff" tab.  On the lower half, use the drop down to select the external program you want to use to do the diffs and merging.  I've installed [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) and like it well enough.  When you're done, click OK.

Now when there is a merge, you can go under Actions->Resolve Conflicts->Launch External Merge Tool.

Comment: I tried this, but at the end, I don't see beyond compare being launched. I see compare files being generated, but that's it. I cannot resolve conflict. Changing this to the standard / default compare doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: You can also access the external merge by right-clicking on the files shown in the file list.

Comment: @echiban You probably have the standard license for Beyond Compare which does not accept 3 way merging. You need to go pro to use it as a git mergetool

Comment: After following all the steps to configure "Launch External Merge Tool" is still dimmed for me, no way to activate it

Comment: @pal4life i had the same issue. restart Sourcetree after doing the above and it was no longer greyed out.

Comment: Also I was not selecting the merge conflict file, once I did that it went fine

Comment: I had to click on the "Uncommited changes" item in the commit list before it un-greyed.

Answer (score 13):

I'm using SourceTree along with TortoiseMerge/Diff, which is very easy and convinient diff/merge tool.

If you'd like to use it as well, then:

1. Get standalone version of TortoiseMerge/Diff (quite old, since it doesn't ship standalone since version 1.6.7 of TortosieSVN, that is since July 2011). Links and details [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26002744/1469208).
2. Unzip `TortoiseIDiff.exe` and `TortoiseMerge.exe` to any folder (`c:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree\extras\` in my case).
3. In SourceTree open `Tools > Options > Diff > External Diff / Merge`. Select `TortoiseMerge` in both dropdown lists.
4. Hit `OK` and point SourceTree to your location of `TortoiseIDiff.exe` and `TortoiseMerge.exe`.

After that, you can select `Resolve Conflicts > Launch External Merge Tool` from context menu on each conflicted file in your local repository. This will open up TortoiseMerge, where you can easily deal with all the conflicts, you have. Once finished, simply close TortoiseMerge (you don't even need to save changes, this will probably be done automatically) and after few seconds SourceTree should handle that gracefully.

The only problem is, that it automatically creates backup copy, even though [proper option is unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26004673/1469208).

Answer (score 5):

When the Resolve Conflicts->Content Menu are disabled, one may be on the Pending files list. We need to select the Conflicted files option from the drop down (top)

hope it helps