# Cannot get TortoiseMerge to work in SourceTree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

Referring to [Resolving Git conflicts in SourceTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156907/resolving-git-conflicts-in-sourcetree) it would seem I have set it up correctly but it doesn't do anything if you can please advise, thanks.

- Ver. of SourceTree: 3.4.13
- Diff Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitMerge.exe
- Arguments: \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"

I know the linked post talks about downloading a version of Tortoise but it is already installed so why doesn't it work? When I right click a file and select External Diff from the context menu?

Note it does work when you right click the file in Windows Explorer context menu by selecting TortoiseGit->Diff

Answer (score 0):

I forgot I did find this out ages ago, an undocumented step is you have to set up an User Environment Variable HOME=%USERPROFILE%