# Install just TortoiseMerge software and context menu items

Tags: tortoisesvn, tortoisemerge

I really love TortoiseMerge (TortoiseSVN's diff/merge software). I can download it standalone as a zip, but I really love when I can select two files and then **right click and from the context menu** click on "diff in tortoise". Is there any way I can install just this tool? I don't want the whole SVN suite.

[TortoiseSVN's download page](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) does not offer TortoiseMerge individually.

Here are TortoiseMerge's official [webpage](http://tortoisesvn.net/TortoiseMerge.html) and [documentation](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseMerge_en/index.html).

Comment: Araxis Merge can do that, but it is a bit pricey.

Comment: @KromStern What is the reason and idea behind suggesting _software B_, if OP is precisely asking about _software A_? Especially, if first is paid, while second is free?

Comment: @trejder: Because A. I think that Araxis Merge is superior and B because this is just a comment. Price is not an issue in OP at all

Comment: @KromStern You're welcome to like any software, you wish and I'm really happy, that you find Araxis Merge so superior and good. Which doesn't change the fact, that your comment / suggestion is off-topic to OP question. And it also suggests paid software, what can be taken by some here as kind of advertisment, which is not welcome in SE. Pointing this to you, was my only intention with above comment. Please, don't take is too personally! :]

Comment: @trejder: I figure that OP is about "I want to have right-click diff on 2 files" topped with "I know Tortoise has that feature", so I have commented, that there is a good tool that can do that out of the box. That's all :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

<s>You can't, sorry.</s> Yes, you can!

<s>According to [this forum thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tortoisesvn/4aq1N9tZPYw/BTdowfGZoQ4J) (from June, 2011, so pretty much over three years old), written by [Stefan Küng](http://tortoisesvn.net/stefan_kueng.html), an author of TortoiseSVN, starting from version 1.7 of TSVN, TortoiseMerge does not ship as standalone.</s>

You can go to [`Tools` folder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/OldFiles/Tools/1.6.7/) on TortoiseSVN's site at SF and get [TortoiseDiff-1.6.7.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/OldFiles/Tools/1.6.7/TortoiseDiff-1.6.7.zip/download) file from there. It still quite outdated (see above notice), but certainly it is a standalone version of TortoiseMerge.

Comment: Thanks man for the solution. I'm thinking maybe just write my own winapi thing to add menu items, that should do the trick huh?

Comment: Thanks man i know of the standalone but i want the standalone to have context menu items on windows. Plus rep for the link though. :)

Comment: As for context menu items, you may try to change your context menu handlers (not so good example [here](http://superuser.com/a/57234/156554), but you can Google out many better). But this involves messing up with your registry, so I'm not sure, if this is worth time spent on this? It is up to you...

Comment: Damn.. looks like it is no longer available... or at least not at that location.

Comment: @psusi I fixed the broken links.

Answer (score 4):

I needed something similar (just a standalone app to make diff files) and was able to copy the following out of the Tortoise install directory (`C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\`) to make TortoiseMerge work on its own (similar to the [accepted answer's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26002744/1037948)).  Maybe extract them from the full installer if you don't have it installed already?

- TortoiseMerge.exe
- libsvn_tsvn.dll
- libapr_tsvn.dll
- libaprutil_tsvn.dll
- vcruntime140.dll
- intl3_tsvn.dll
- libsasl.dll
- mfc140u.dll
- msvcp140.dll

As far as the context-menu entry:

- [How add context menu item to Windows Explorer for folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders) and probably needing multiple "%" placeholders (e.g. `myprogrampath\path\path\executable.exe %1 %2`)
- https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of context menu items, a good workaround is to put it in the SendTo folder

Comment: Open file explorer then enter in the address bar:  shell:sendto