# Disable automatic backups in SourceTree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree together with TortoiseDiff/Merge. Every time I save a file there, after resolving all conflicts, SourceTree handles everything perfectly, except for the fact, that it always create a backup file `[name].orig`.

This is extremely irritating for me, as I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> such file each time and confirm annoying dialogs.

How can I get rid of this?

I thought, that this will be as simple as unchecking `Tools > Options > Keep backups on destrictive operations`. But, apparently this is not enough or this option controls some other behaviour of SourceTree.

Comment: Have you read this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251681/git-mergetool-generates-unwanted-orig-files

Comment: I don't use SourceTree anymore. However, you have a great point and I think you should write this as an answer. Simply explain, that this seems to be a Git, not SourceTree feature and link to the answer, which explains how to disable this. I'll accept your answer and bring you some reputation, if you care for that.

Comment: I will, Thanks.
Do you use another tool? I'm also leaving SourceTree to learn more about git commands, but for it's still my favourite tool to see what's going on..

Comment: I've changed drastically my Git-like behavior. I don't actually use any visual tool for it as I don't find any need for this. For managing git repositories and changes command line in form of Git for Windows (Git Bash) is all that I need. And for tracking changes in files I use `Modific` plugin for Sublime Text 3. As I changed in the same time my IDE editor (mainly for perfect linter plugin in it) from Netbeans + SourceTree used before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we talk..
This can be caused by a git settings instead of SourceTree/another tool settings.

Try doing this:

> git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false

From: 
[Git mergetool generates unwanted .orig files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251681/git-mergetool-generates-unwanted-orig-files)